# NserviceBus 6 use RabbitMQTransport not working

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, rabbitmq-exchange, nservicebus6

We are using NSB v6.4.3, NServiceBus.RabbitMQ v4.4.1, RabbitMQ.Client v5.0.1. My Queues are created automatically, but I received this error and soon as I send a message to my queue.

**"title": "Channel has been closed: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text=\"NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'SelfDriving.NServicebus' in vhost '/'\", classId=60, methodId=40, cause=.",
            "detail": "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at NServiceBus.MutateOutgoingTransportMessageBehavior.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at NServiceBus.SerializeMessageConnector.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at NServiceBus.MutateOutgoingMessageBehavior.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at NServiceBus.UnicastSendRouterConnector.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at SelfDriving.Api.Controllers.BasicController.d__19.MoveNext() in C:\Source\innovate\self_driving_ideas.cs\SelfDriving.Api\Controllers\BasicController.cs:line 61\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at SelfDriving.Api.Controllers.FiltersController.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Source\innovate\self_driving_ideas.cs\SelfDriving.Api\Controllers\FiltersController.cs:line 188\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at SelfDriving.Api.Controllers.FiltersController.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Source\innovate\self_driving_ideas.cs\SelfDriving.Api\Controllers\FiltersController.cs:line 168\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
            "code": "System.Exception"**

I don't have any problem when I'm using MsmqTransport
This is my configuration code

```
    config = new EndpointConfiguration("SelfDriving.NServiceBus");
config.AssemblyScanner();
config.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
config.LimitMessageProcessingConcurrencyTo(1);
var recoverability = config.Recoverability();
recoverability.Immediate( customizations: immediate => { immediate.NumberOfRetries(3);});
DefaultFactory defaultFactory = LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory>();
defaultFactory.Directory("c:\storage\Bus");
defaultFactory.Level(LogLevel.Error);
config.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
config.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit", TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
var rabbitMQTransport = config.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>().Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.ReceiveOnly);
var rabbitMQRouting = rabbitMQTransport.Routing();
rabbitMQRouting.RouteToEndpoint(assembly: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (BasicMessage)),destination: "SelfDriving.NServiceBus");
config.SendOnly();
var endpointInstance = Endpoint.Start(config).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue happened because RabbitMQ is case sensitive and I was sending it to **SelfDriving.NServicebus** which is a wrong end point instead of **SelfDriving.NServicebus** 
This issue resolved as soon as I change the endpoint name

Comment: (a) your answer helped me.  but (b) the items you yellow highlighted, look like the same CaSe to me. (??)  Can you add a note to your answer that says "notice the (third or fourth or fifth letter) of "X" that was a different case.

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring your endpoint as SendOnly. That means there's no incoming queue. But you also configure routing to send all messages inside the assembly in which `BasicMessage` is located to this exact same endpoint.

That's causing the issue `no exchange 'SelfDriving.NServicebus'`

If you remove the SendOnly option it'll probably work.

Comment: But  I have no problem with sending and receiving messages when I'm using MsmqTransport.  As soon as I removed the SendOnly part, I was not able to start the service bus. and I have this error: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text="NOT_FOUND - no queue 'SelfDriving.NServicebus' in vhost '/'", classId=60, methodId=20, cause=